# How I can calculate the algebraic rank of $C(ℚ)$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let us consider the elliptic curve $C$ over $ℚ$ in Weierstrass form

$$C:y²=x³+1$$

How I can calculate the algebraic rank of $C(ℚ)$.

Comment: Your particular curve is especially well studied, but in general, the answer to this is just to ask Sage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rank of this curve is $0$. Extensive computations for all curves $y^2=x^3+k$ in the range $|k| \leq10^5$ was made by Gebel, Pethö and Zimmer in their paper On Mordell's Equation which you may find here

http://www.inf.unideb.hu/~pethoe/cikkek/67_MORDELL.pdf

The table of their results may be resurrected here

http://web.archive.org/web/20040816044321/http://emmy.math.uni-sb.de/~simath/MORDELL/MORDELL+

Comment: @ Jesper Petersen: So there is no points $(x,y)$ solutions of that equation such that $x$ and $y$ are rationals or integers.

Comment: There are the torsion points which are the points of finite order according to the group law. These have $x \in \{-1, 0, 2\}$. There are no other points, i.e. none of infinite order.